# What's the designated initializer of `UIImage` class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimage

I have searched the `UIImage` class for it's designated initializer, but there wasn't one. What's the designated initializer of `UIImage`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply: there isn't one.  There are multiple ways to create a `UIImage`, and they don't necessarily share code paths, which means they don't reduce to a common initializer.

Comment: I just realized the designated initializer is not *required*. Thanks :)